# Commonly used distributions defined with support $[0,1]$

Tags: probability

Help name some commonly used distributions defined over $[0,1]$ (i.e. support $[0,1]$), for example, uniform distribution over $[0,1]$, beta distribution. Any others?

Comment: You mean the _range_ of the density function is in $[0,1]$? Consider standard Gaussian density.

Comment: @iseliget Thanks for comment. Sorry for not being clear. I edited the question.

Comment: If you mean $\operatorname{supp}(\mu) \subseteq [0, 1]$, Bernoulli distribution would be one such example, too.

Comment: The beta family of distributions (which includes the continuous uniform) seems to be the most widely used. See the Wikipedia article for graphs of some PDFs and CDFs; also, formulas for means and variances. In Bayesian statistics, widely used as prior distributions for binomial success probability $p$ (and other distributions based on Bernoulli trials).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Triangular distribution on $[0,1]$, trapezoidal distribution on $[0,1]$ truncated normal distribution on $[0,1]$,...

These are not commonly used as far as I know, but most other commonly used distributions of these form are a special case of the beta distribution.

See [this wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions#Supported_on_a_bounded_interval) for more of them.